# MapServer runtime execution: Cannot evaluate expression, no item index defined error

Tags: wms, mapserver, error, regular-expression

I'm trying MapServer's run-time substitution to dynamically set my Mapfile's CLASS EXPRESSION values.

The expressions take the form of:

```
CLASS
    EXPRESSION (([my_attr_col] >= num_1) && ([my_attr_col] < num_2))
    ...
END
```

When manually setting the expression values (not using run-time substitution) it works. (And only seems to do so when I use no quotes at all.)

When trying to pass the expression in dynamically with run-time substitution, then I add a VALIDATION block:

```
VALIDATION
    'my_attr'    '^[\s\S]*$'
END
```

and I modify the CLASS EXPRESSIONs along these lines:

```
CLASS
    EXPRESSION '%my_attr%'
    ...
END
```

and I then append and send the information via the query URL.

However, I get this error:

```
msEvalExpression(): General error message. Cannot evaluate expression, no item index defined.
```

I've tried many permutations of quotes and regex filtering but I can't seem to figure out what would be accepted by MapServer.

Comment: Have you already tried to validate with '.*'? And how does your request look &my_attr=.... Does it contain "&&" like in your example of the hand written mapfile expression?

Comment: Hi, yes, I'm presently trying with '.*' The request looks like this: `http://url_address/cgi-bin/mapserv.fcgi?my_attr=((%5Bmy_attr_col%5D%20%3E=%20num_1)%20&&%20(%5Bmy_attr_col%5D%20%3C%20num_2))&etc...`

Comment: I would test with much more simple variable first. Like `EXPRESSION ([my_attr_col] >%test%)` and then having `&test=1` in the request. When you get it to work you know that the variable gets transferred into EXPRESSION and the rest is making odd characters to pass the GET request, URL-encoding, and validation.

Comment: Yeah that works much better. I've removed anything 'non-ordinary' from the URL query and now it works fine.